# Spark Dataset - groupBy.agg(max(column),collect_list(column))

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset on `groupby("_1","_2","_3","_4").agg(max("_5").as("time"),collect_list("_6").as("value"))` returns a dataset which has the grouped data for four columns and `max` of time column and `collect_list` which has all the values for that grouped data like `[5,1]` but all I want for `_6` is the value matching all the grouped columns and also max("_5").as("time") not only for the grouped columns

Code below:

```
val data = Seq(("thing1",1,1,"Temperature",1551501300000L,"5"),("thing1",1,1,"Temperature",1551502200000L,"1"))

 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
 val dataSet = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
 import spark.implicits._
 val testDS = dataSet.toDS()
 testDS.groupby("_1","_2","_3","_4").agg(max("_5").as("time"),collect_list("_6").as("value")).show()
```

Output:

```
 |  _1     |  _2  |  _3  |  _4        |  time          |  value  |
 |thingId1 |  1   |  1   |Temperature |  1551502200000 | [5,1]   |
```

Required Output

```
 |  _1     |  _2  |  _3  |  _4        |  time          |  value  |
 |thingId1 |  1   |  1   |Temperature |  1551502200000 | 1       |
```

I don't want value 5 to be in the value column as its not comes under the criteria `max("time")` all I need is 1 in value column as the it only matches the conditions of all the grouped columns and `max("time")`.

How to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this neatly and **without** having to use a `Window` function by using the argmax logic like so:

```
val data = Seq(("thing1",1,1,"Temperature",1551501300000L,"5"), 
               ("thing1",1,1,"Temperature",1551502200000L,"1")).toDF

data.groupBy("_1","_2","_3","_4").agg(
     max(struct("_5", "_6")).as("argmax")).select("_1","_2","_3","_4", "argmax.*").show

+------+---+---+-----------+-------------+---+
|    _1| _2| _3|         _4|           _5| _6|
+------+---+---+-----------+-------------+---+
|thing1|  1|  1|Temperature|1551502200000|  1|
+------+---+---+-----------+-------------+---+
```

When you use a `max` on a `struct` in spark it returns the `struct` with the highest first value and if there are `structs` with equal first values then it goes to the second value and so on and so forth. Once we have the `max` `struct` you can then extract the values from the `struct` by using the `*` wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window` functions in this scenario:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("_1","_2","_3","_4").orderBy(desc("_5"))

testDS.withColumn("rowSelector", row_number() over windowSpec)
    .where($"rowSelector" === 1)
    .drop($"rowSelector")
    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------+---+---+-----------+-------------+---+
|_1    |_2 |_3 |_4         |_5           |_6 |
+------+---+---+-----------+-------------+---+
|thing1|1  |1  |Temperature|1551502200000|1  |
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it helped me..